# Blender / Python convert form radians to degrees;

Tags: python

I'd like to create a text object that displays the rotation angle, in degrees, of an object.

I found this code snippet which does almost exactly what I want, except gives units in radians.

I'm a noob when it comes to Python & Blender. Can someone show me how to make this read in degrees? I assume there is a convert function, but i have no idea how to integrate one.

Thanks in advance.

````
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = scene.objects['Text']

def recalculate_text(scene):
    obj.data.body = f'{bpy.data.objects["Cylinder.003"].rotation_euler[0]}'

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(recalculate_text)
```
````

Comment: degree = radian*(180/pi)

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import degrees

def recalculate_text(scene): # fail when rotation_mode in {QUATERNION, AXIS_ANGLE}
    obj.data.body = f'{degrees(bpy.data.objects["Cylinder.003"].rotation_euler[0])}'
```

or

```
def recalculate_text(scene): # fail when rotation_mode in {QUATERNION, AXIS_ANGLE}
    obj.data.body = f'{bpy.data.objects["Cylinder.003"].rotation_euler[0] * 57.29577951308232}'
```

Comment: That's great, thanks alot. FYI for anyone reading this in the future, the first snippet has "degrees" spleed as "degress". Otherwise perfect.